# Looping through list to get "Checked" items and assign them to a property - HTTPPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, object, viewmodel

I'm trying to get the foreach loop to check through the checklistbox and return the ID of the ietms which are selected and set them to the Month property in my ViewModel. So far, I've got the checklistbox dispayed on the screen and got the right parameters in ViewModel (I hope). Currently, the foreach statement reaches an error as the list is null. How can I solve this?

Here is the controller:

```
public class SchedulerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Scheduler
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SchedulerIndex()
    {

        List<Values> lst = new List<Values>();
        List<Values> lst2 = new List<Values>();
        List<Values> lst3 = new List<Values>();


        foreach (Values.Months month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values.Months)))
        {
            lst.Add(new Values { Month = month, IsChecked = false });
        }

        foreach (Values.DaysOfTheWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Values.DaysOfTheWeek)))
        {
            lst2.Add(new Values { DaysOfWeek = day, IsChecked = false });
        }


        //var DaysOfTheMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, 31);

        //foreach (var days in DaysOfTheMonth)
        //{
        //    lst3.Add(new Values { DayOfMonth = days, IsChecked = false });
        //}

        Values val = new Values();
        val.Jobs = new List<SelectListItem>();
        val.Jobs.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Email", Value = "1", Selected = false });
        val.Jobs.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Backup", Value = "2", Selected = false });
        val.Jobs.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Start Application", Value = "3", Selected = false });
        val.Jobs.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Job4", Value = "4", Selected = false });
        val.Jobs.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Job5", Value = "5", Selected = false });




        List<Values> month11 = new List<Values>();
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 0, monthName = "Jan", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 1, monthName = "Feb", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 2, monthName = "Mar", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 3, monthName = "Apr", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 4, monthName = "May", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 5, monthName = "Jun", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 6, monthName = "Jul", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 7, monthName = "Aug", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 8, monthName = "Sep", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 9, monthName = "Oct", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 10, monthName = "Nov", IsChecked = false });
        month11.Add(new Values { monthID = 11, monthName = "Dec", IsChecked = false });



        List<Values> day6 = new List<Values>();
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 0, dayName = "Mon", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 1, dayName = "Tue", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 2, dayName = "Wed", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 3, dayName = "Thu", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 4, dayName = "Fri", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 5, dayName = "Sat", IsChecked = false });
        day6.Add(new Values { dayID = 6, dayName = "Sun", IsChecked = false });

        val.MonthInfo = month11;

        val.DayInfo = day6;

        ViewBag.lst = lst;
        ViewBag.lst2 = lst2;
        ViewBag.lst3 = lst3;

        return View(val);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ScheduleInfo(int Job, int Second, int Minute, int Hour, object Month, object DaysOfWeek)//,  string Month, string DaysOfWeek)// int DayOfMonth)
    {
        var val = new Values();

        val.Job = Job;
        val.Second = Second;
        val.Minute = Minute;
        val.Hour = Hour;


        foreach(var month in val.MonthInfo)
        {
            if (month.IsChecked == true)
            {
                val.Month = month.monthID;
            }
        }

        foreach (var day in val.DayInfo)
        {
            if (day.IsChecked == true)
            {
                val.DaysOfWeek = day.dayID;
            }
        }

        //val.Month = (int)((Values.Months)Enum.Parse(typeof(Values.Months), Month));
        //val.DaysOfWeek = (int)((Values.DaysOfTheWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(Values.DaysOfTheWeek), DaysOfWeek));


        //        val.DayOfMonth = DayOfMonth; 

        return View();
    }


}
```

Here is the ViewModel (i'm not using enum, I plan on getting rid of that):

```
        public enum Months
    {
        Jan = 0,
        Feb = 1,
        Mar = 2,
        Apr = 3,
        May = 4,
        Jun = 5,
        Jul = 6,
        Aug = 7,
        Sep = 8,
        Oct = 9,
        Nov = 10,
        Dec = 11
    }

    public enum DaysOfTheWeek
    {
        Mon = 0,
        Tue = 1,
        Wed = 2,
        Thu = 3,
        Fri = 4,
        Sat = 5,
        Sun = 6
    }

    public int DayOfMonth { get; set; }

    public object Month { get; set; }

    public object DaysOfWeek { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }

    public int Job { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Jobs { get; set; }

    public int monthID { get; set; }
    public string monthName { get; set; }
    public List<Values> MonthInfo { get; set; }

    public int dayID { get; set; }
    public string dayName { get; set; }

    public List<Values> DayInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the view:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ScheduleInfo", "Scheduler", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <center>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Job, Model.Jobs)
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; padding-right:100px">
            <div class=" col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Second, "Second")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Second)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; padding-right:100px">
            <div class=" col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Minute, "Minute")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Minute)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block; padding-right:100px">
            <div class=" col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hour, "Hour")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hour)
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <br />
    <br />

    <center>
        <div class="col-1">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the month(s) the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.monthID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.monthName)
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.MonthInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].monthID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.MonthInfo[i].monthName)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>

    <center>
        <div class="col-2">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the day(s) the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.dayID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.dayName)
                @for(int i = 0; i < Model.DayInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].dayID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.DayInfo[i].dayName)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </center>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" />

}
```

Comment: Please check if the name for the checkboxes are rendered correctly

Comment: I guess this is not a code-review, but, instead of `if(isChecked == true)` you can write just `if(isChecked)`, and bool is 'false' by default, so explicitly inicializing `bool IsChecked = false` is just plain redundant

Comment: You need to bind to you model in the POST method

Comment: I've had a look and yes, they are rendered correctly

Comment: The POST method needs to be `public ActionResult ScheduleInfo(Values model)` (assuming the model in your view is `@model Values`)

Comment: That's solved it, thank you!  How do I accept that as the answer?